# CakePHP 1.3: Check if Date is today during a find operation in a model

Tags: cakephp

I would like to find members have signed up today. I am not sure, if this is the best way, but this is what I have:

```
function getMembersToday(){
    $members = $this->find(
        'count',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.created' => //Expression with today's date
            )
        )
    );

    return $members;
}
```

I want to return all users created today as a 'count'. How do I go about accomplishing this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the functions:

**MySQL:**`'User.created' => 'CURDATE()'`
**SQLite:**`"User.created" => "date('now')"`
**PostgreSQL:**`"User.created" => 'now()::date'`
**Oracle:**`"User.created" => 'SYSDATE'`

Comment: Thanks for replying. This, however, does not work correctly. The use of `CURDATE()` is accurate, but `User.created` does not match it. In this situation `CURDATE() = 2011-12-12' and `User.created = 2011-12-12 23:37:24`. Those 2 numbers do not match. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was able to fix it with DATEDIFF... see addition to your post..thanks